# Resetting Email/Password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a page setup to reset the user's email address password and the users zip_code for an application. I have it working correctly however, if for example I want to just change the zip code my validation will not allow it due to it reading the email as already existing in the database and returns an error. What is the best way around this? I could create a controller for each field and do it individually but I feel there is some if statement I could use maybe?

**Controller:**

```
enter        
public function getEditUser() {
    $userdata = array(
        'email'            => Input::get('email'),
        'password'         => Input::get('password'),
        'confirm_password' => Input::get('confirm_password'),
        'user_zip_code'    => Input::get('user_zip_code')
    );

    $rules = array(
        'email'            => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'password'         => 'required|min:5',
        'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
        'user_zip_code'    => 'required'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($userdata, $rules);
    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard/edit/account')->withErrors($validation)       
            ->withInput();
    }

    $userdata['password']         = Hash::make($userdata['password']);
    $userdata['confirm_password'] = Hash::make($userdata['confirm_password']);

    User::find(Auth::user()->id)->update($userdata);

    return Redirect::to('dashboard');
}
```

Unique needs to be in place obviously so it doesn't get matched with another account

Also my email is set through Auth..`Auth::user()->email` if that helps

Comment: Assigning a hash to `$userdata['confirm_password'] = Hash::make(…)` makes no sense. It is not possible to compare the two hashes, so either you don't use `$userdata['confirm_password']` afterwards, or the generated hash is terribly unsafe and doesn't use a salt.

Comment: That was unrelated to my question. The password and confirm_password is simply just to compare the two passwords in validation. The confirm password does go into a database and that's why they are hashed once passing validation. The confirm password field is NOT used anywhere else except to create an account and to change account information(as what you see here).

Comment: I imagine I could remove confirm_password for saving into my database and just have password. If that's what your concern was? I really have no need for it in there. I will check that out though! Thanks!

Comment: that's why they are hashed AFTER validation. they are being compared and then hashed then stored. You can see only once they pass validation do they get hashed...then they are updated.

Comment: Ok i got it, the hash _is_ secure and salted, and `$userdata['confirm_password']` is really not used anywhere. I deleted my previous comment, just wanted to be sure the hash is secure.

Comment: exactly! Thank you for your concern though. I wasn't trying to be rude by my "unrelated question" remark. i just know some admins on here are a stickler for sticking to the point. But thanks again for trying to make sure my application is secure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the validation unique rule to ignore the current id

```
$rules = array(
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Auth::user()->id,
                'password' => 'required|min:5',
                'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
                'user_zip_code' => 'required'
            );
```

[See here for more info from the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: I looked all the way up and down that page trying to find that. Thanks alot!